Cannot build VirtualBox Guest Additions
Running VBoxLinux.run builds okay but then fails, referring me to the vboxadd-setup.log which I have posted below via pastebin
vboxadd-setup.log is posted here: https://pastebin.com/77m5h7N5]vboxadd-setup.log
Host distro and versions of virtualbox packages
Arch linux on 6.8.2-arch1-1 kernel

['virtualbox', '(7.0.14-2)']
['virtualbox-host-modules-arch', '(7.0.14-15)']
['virtualbox-guest-iso', '(7.0.14-1)']
['virtualbox-ext-oracle', '(7.0.14-1)']
['xf86-video-vmware', '(13.3.0-4)']
['virtualbox-guest-utils', '(7.0.14-2)']
['virtualbox-sdk', '(6.1.38-1)']
   

Guest distro and versions of virtualbox packages
Arch linux on 6.8.2-arch1-1 kernel

['virtualbox-guest-iso', '(7.0.2-1)']
['xf86-video-vmware', '(13.4.0-1)'] 
['virtualbox-guest-utils', '(7.0.14-2)']

systemctl status vboxadd: the status of the GuestAdditions service and the failed install
vboxadd.service
    Loaded: loaded (/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-7.0.14/init/vboxadd; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-03-29 06:06:17 PDT; 7h ago
    Process: 329 ExecStart=/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-7.0.14/init/vboxadd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 329 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 9495)
    Memory: 219.5M (peak: 358.4M)
        CPU: 28.979s
    CGroup: /system.slice/vboxadd.service
            ├─1158 /usr/bin/VBoxDRMClient
            └─1160 /usr/sbin/VBoxService --pidfile /var/run/vboxadd-service.sh

Mar 29 06:06:07 flip vboxadd-service.sh[1161]: VirtualBox Guest Addition service started.
Mar 29 06:06:16 flip vboxadd[1871]: VirtualBox Guest Additions: kernel modules were not reloaded
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip vboxadd[329]: VirtualBox Guest Additions: kernel modules and services were not reloaded
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip vboxadd[329]: The log file /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log may contain further information.
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip systemd[1]: vboxadd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip systemd[1]: vboxadd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip systemd[1]: vboxadd.service: Unit process 1158 (VBoxDRMClient) remains running after unit stopped.
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip systemd[1]: vboxadd.service: Unit process 1160 (VBoxService) remains running after unit stopped.
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip systemd[1]: Failed to start vboxadd.service.
Mar 29 06:06:17 flip systemd[1]: vboxadd.service: Consumed 12.988s CPU time, 358.4M memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.


We're going to need more information: 1) what distro/version, 2) post the contents of /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log (add to your question, please).

@ajgringo619   Note that Arch does not have versioned releases but is instead a general rolling release. I had put the information you request but it was not with obvious labels. I have put more obvious labels Thanks for your response

Thanks for that. You should add arch linux as a tag for better viewability. I run Arch with the same version of Virtualbox as you, built with no issues. First of all, you don't need xf86-video-vmware or virtualbox-guest-utils on the host. Second, you don't need virtualbox-guest-iso on the guest. Third, if you use virtualbox-guest-utils you do not need to install via VBoxLinux.run (it will conflict with virtualbox-guest-utils). Fourth, why did you install such as old version of the Virtualbox SDK?

@ajgringo619 Agh! Well with so much muck about it's a wonder I've had things working for all these years. When I installed the SDK it was brand spanking new but I never found much to do with it so... I've removed the crud you mention but still no joy. This VM is ancient (with the GuestAdds working!) so after your comment I'm just going to go ahead and roll out a fresh one. Thanks for the help.
